# Best spot to gold farm in hell as a Barbarian?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

Due to wanting to progress together with my friends who are a teeny bit slower, I've not wanted to progress past into Inferno. I have a lvl 60 Barbarian who is sufficiently decked in Inferno-Act1 ready gear (resist all, defense, etc) and so have no problems surviving Act 3/4 Hell solo even if I switch out some gear for MF/GF gear.

I've been doing Siegebreaker runs with 5 neph valor (bridge of korikk + caverns of frost or depths level 3 until 5 stacks + siegebreaker) which got a little boring. I continue onwards past Cydaea and Azmodan sometimes but it's a fair bit of walk starting from Siegebreaker.

So my question is, which is the most profitable gold farm spot for a Barbarian in Act 3/4 Hell? This question is specifically for Barbarian considering we are NOT ranged (i know there are some nice spots for DHs/Wizards, don't they all) and also considering Grim Harvest might have some use ...

Comment: The best gold farm spot (boring as hell) is actually the jar run in act 1 in the area leading up to the 4 pillars before the skeleton king.  With all gold find gear you can get maybe 200-300k an hour

Comment: @yx. Even after they hot-nerfed the ashes' gold drop chance?

Comment: No. The hotfix has completely destroyed gold-farming from ashes.

Comment: I was thinking either Act IV (various places to farm bosses or angels), or perhaps the treasure hoarder monster in Act I inferno. Although the most efficient would probably be Warden/Butcher runs.

Comment: yes i was doing that gold farm spot up until they nerfed it 2 days ago

Comment: I guess I need to keep up with hotfixes :P  Did the fix the other jar farm in act 4?

Answer (score 3):

I find the first quest of Act 1 on Inferno is a good place to farm gold after the nerfs to the other hot spots recently, essentially start from the 'Rumford at the gate' quest, and clear the area outside of New Tristram followed by clearing Old Tristram, killing the 3 Wretched Mothers and the Queen, and then returning the quest and starting all over again.

During this clear you have the possibility to find:

- the 'Cave Under The Well' zone, which is a wishing well with stacks of gold inside
- the 'Dank Cellar' zone, which has a treasure horder mob inside
- the 'Quality Well' zone, an easter egg zone similar to the Cave Under The Well: stacks of gold
- a couple of other randomly selected levels, one of which may contain an elite pack
- the cellar within Old Tristram (near the Blacksmith) has the possibility to spawn a treasure goblin

As a general rule, I go for more clears = more gold, so will skip any cellar with an elite in them. On a poor run (neither of the wells spawn and you don't get the treasure horder) you will make about 10k excluding selling gems that drop.

The wells are worth 10-20k each depending on your gold find.

The dank cellar is worth 10-50k depending on the current cost of gems on the auction house.

Each clear should take no more than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Whimseyshire on Hell mode seems to be the best for me - farmed for 30 minutes (2 runs) and made about 80k. farmed with lvl 60 (average geared) monk.

Answer (score 2):

Act 1 HELL from start to skeleton king brings me in about 50K.